# Merge two data frames by grepl in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have two data frames such that:

```
df1<-data.frame(x=c("abc", "def", "ghi", NA), y=1:4)
df1
    x y
1 abc 1
2 def 2
3 ghi 3
4 NA  4
df2<-data.frame(x=c("a", "i"), z=4:5)
df2
  x z
1 a 4
2 i 5
```

What I wanted is to merge `df1` and `df2` by grepl df2's `x` in df2's `x` such that a desired outcome would be:

```
df3
    x y  z
1 abc 1  4
2 def 2 NA
3 ghi 3  5
4 NA  4  NA
```

The actual data frames are much bigger and seems to need a few lines for that. I am wondering whether there might be an easily way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a one-liner which left joins on a search for `df2.x` in `df1.x` :

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select df1.*, df2.z from df1 left join df2 on instr(df1.x,  df2.x)")
```

giving:

```
     x y  z
1  abc 1  4
2  def 2 NA
3  ghi 3  5
4 <NA> 4 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that will work if every element of df2 has a single match to an element of df1:

```
# initialize new varible with NAs
df1$z <- NA
# fill in matching indices with df2$z
df1$z[sapply(df2$x, function(i) grep(i, df1$x, fixed=TRUE))] <- df2$z
```

`sapply(df2$x, function(i) grep(i, df1$x, fixed=TRUE))` will run through each element of `df2$x` and find the matching position within `df1$x`, the output will be a vector.

---

To make this robust to non-matches between the two, you could do the following. In the example below, "j" does not find a match. The `[1]` at the end of `grep` forces an NA instead of the default `integer(0)`.

```
# get indices match with NAs for non-matches
matches <- unlist(lapply(c("a", "j"), function(i) grep(i, df1$x, fixed=TRUE)[1]))
matches
[1]  1 NA
```

Now, use this with `is.na` to subset the subsetting vectors.

```
df1$z[matches[!is.na(matches)]] <- df2$z[!is.na(matches)]
df1
     x y  z
1  abc 1  4
2  def 2 NA
3  ghi 3 NA
4 <NA> 4 NA
```

Comment: Are you able to do this using dplyr ?