# combining two dataframes in R function of "egrep"-like formulas

Tags: r, dataframe

please may I ask for a piece of advise regarding merging 2 `data.frames`:

```
A <- data.frame(z=c("a*b", "c*d", "d*e", "e*f"), t =c(1, 2, 3, 4))

B <- data.frame(z=c("a*b::x*y", "c", "", "g*h"), t =c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

function of the criteria :

if "the elements in the 1st column of A could be found among the elements of the 1st column of B" i.e.

for the example above, we shall combine in the results only the row with "a*b" of A with the row with "a*b::x*y" of B.

Comment: It is not very clear what you expect. can you provide full expected output for your example

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have been trying the following formula:

```
  sqldf("select B.*, A.* from B left join A on instr(B.z,  A.z)")
```

after I've just found some inspiration in another post :

[Merge two data frames by grepl in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899141/merge-two-data-frames-by-grepl-in-r)